# Learning parameters of dynamic Bayesian network using BNT

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, bayesian-networks

I am trying to create a Dynamic Bayesian Network using Bayesian Network Toolbox (BNT) in Matlab. I have followed the tutorial closely, and end up with the following code:

```
T=2;
names = {'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X7', 'X8', 'X9', 'X10', 'X11', 'X12'};
ss = length(names);
onodes=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12];
intrac = {
  'X1', 'X2';
  'X3', 'X4';
  'X6', 'X7';
  'X7', 'X8';
  'X10', 'X11';
  'X10', 'X12';
  'X11', 'X12';
  };
[intra, names] = mk_adj_mat(intrac, names, 1);
interc = {
   'X1', 'X1';
   'X2', 'X2';
   'X3', 'X3';
   'X4', 'X4';
   'X5', 'X5';
   'X6', 'X6';
   'X7', 'X7';
   'X8', 'X8';
   'X9', 'X9';
   'X10', 'X10';
   'X11', 'X11';
   'X12', 'X12';
   };
inter = mk_adj_mat(interc, names, 0);  
dnodes = 1:ss; 
ns = [3 3 3 2 4 5 2 2 4 5 4 5]; 
ns(stringmatch('X1',names))=3;
ns(stringmatch('X2',names))=3;
ns(stringmatch('X3',names))=3;
ns(stringmatch('X4',names))=2;
ns(stringmatch('X5',names))=4;
ns(stringmatch('X6',names))=5;
ns(stringmatch('X7',names))=2;
ns(stringmatch('X8',names))=2;
ns(stringmatch('X9',names))=4;
ns(stringmatch('X10',names))=5;
ns(stringmatch('X11',names))=4;
ns(stringmatch('X12',names))=5;

bnet = mk_dbn(intra, inter, ns, 'discrete', dnodes);
for i=1:2*ss
  bnet.CPD{i} = tabular_CPD(bnet, i);
end
allcases=importdata('Myfile.txt',',');
ncases = size(allcases.data,1);
cases = cell(1, ncases);
for i=1:ncases
  cases{i} = cell(ss,T);
  dataentry=allcases.data(i,:);
  ev=uint8([dataentry(1:12)' dataentry(13:24)']);
  cases{i} = num2cell(ev);
end
engine2 = smoother_engine(jtree_2TBN_inf_engine(bnet));
%engine2 = jtree_2TBN_inf_engine(bnet);
[bnt, LL, engine2] = learn_params_dbn_em(engine2, cases, 'max_iter', 20);
```

When I try to run it, the following error shows up:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in discrete_CPD/convert_to_table (line 14)
T = CPT(index{:});

Error in discrete_CPD/convert_to_pot (line 20)
   T = convert_to_table(CPD, domain, evidence);


Error in jtree_2TBN_inf_engine/fwd1 (line 11)
  CPDpot{n} = convert_to_pot(bnet.CPD{e}, engine.pot_type, fam(:), ev);

Error in smoother_engine/enter_evidence (line 12)
[f{1}, ll(1)] = fwd1(engine.tbn_engine, ev(:,1), 1);

Error in learn_params_dbn_em>EM_step (line 131)
  [engine, ll] = enter_evidence(engine, evidence);

Error in learn_params_dbn_em (line 82)
  [engine, loglik, logpost] = EM_step(engine, evidence, temperature);
```

Can someone help me with this error? I think there is something to do with the way I create my tabular CPDs, because I when I looked into the CPDs in bnet, they are all 1*1 tabular. My CPDs were created the same way as the tutorial did. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Update: I just figured this error has nothing to do with the tabular CPDs.

Comment: Update#2: I just sampled the entire network, it learns the parameters fine with the sampled data. So I think my problem is in my dataset. Looking into it now

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, there is something wrong with the data set. In my dataset, I used one cell for all data entries, rather than one cell for each data entry.
Now the code works correctly.